# Date table in SSAS Tabular model not working

Tags: powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012

I built an SSAS Tabular model cube and created a date table using calendarauto(). I have marked it as a date table and created a relationship with the fact table using the date column, and both columns have a Datetime data type.
When I analyze the data using excel, the date filter is not working correctly. For example, when I filter on the year 2021, it gives me row values for the year 2019 also, but if I use the date column from the fact table, I get the correct results.
When I analyze the Tabular cube using Power BI, it works right.
Could you please suggest what exactly is going wrong with our date table?

When I put the Fact table date column and date table date column on excel it looks like the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: It could be a date formatting issue, you are connecting a date time column to a date column. Use or create a Key column as suggested with database and dimensional modeling best practice so dd/mm/yyyy would be for the 01/02/2021 20210201, use those key to join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think that is a bad IDEA to use CALENDARAUTO because it searching for all date columns from your model (and if you have a Customer with a born date eg. 1912-02-02, then you create a big table from that date).

> CALENDARAUTO ignores calculated tables and calculated columns
> searching for date columns. Only the imported columns are analyzed to
> search for date columns.
>
> Internally, CALENDARAUTO calls CALENDAR providing a date range that
> include all the days in the range of years referenced by data in the
> model, according to the following rules:
>
> The earliest date in the model which is not in a calculated column or
> calculated table is taken as the MinDate. The latest date in the model
> which is not in a calculated column or calculated table is taken as
> the MaxDate. The date range returned is dates between the beginning of
> the fiscal year associated with MinDate and the end of the fiscal year
> associated with MaxDate.

A better idea is to use CALENDAR where you have more control

```
CALENDAR (
    DATE ( 2005, 1, 1 ),
    DATE ( 2015, 12, 31 )
)
```

To the topic. Are you sure that you make a relationship on THIS column (in your fact table)? Check also Cross Filtering Behavior -> OnDirection/BothDirection; Show your relationship detail.

Comment: I have a relationship between the date table and the fact table, and I have tried the filter type to OneDirection/BothDirection
when I put out the fact table date column and date table date column, it looks like the screenshot on the above post. For example, 2021-01-01 is connected to 2019-01-01, 2019-01-02-----2021-12-31
And then 2019-01-02 is connected to 2019-01-01  to 2021-12 31 and so on. It acts like there is no relationship between the two tables.  But I have one too many relationships
but when I connect to the cube live using Power BI, it works correctly.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try to add a measure? Default Tabular engine compute a crossjoin if you don't add any measure (and this is ok).

Comment: What kind of measure? I have measures in my fact table that use the time intelligence function, so I needed to use a date table.

What kind of measure should I create?

Comment: Just add any measure, count of row - whatever

Comment: Ok, Thanks  I created a count measure on the date table, and when I added the measure on the table visual, it works fine
so that means If I  use a date filter on my table, I have to add the measure on the visual every time I analyze the data on Excel?

Comment: You should analyze your data in excel always in measure context. Pulling only Attributes will generate ALWAYS cross join. For example, if you have a table Product and ProductCategory and you grap ProductName from Product and ProductCategoryName from ProductCategory then you get every combination (even if you don't have it). Use a measure.